How to keep text in TextField Android Java?
In Android java, I want if I enter 2-byte characters or special characters, it will not be accepted.
If you enter on the Romaji keyboard, the transcription will not be received.
For example: If I enter "Joshimaru", it will remain "Joshimaru" at 1 byte. Do not convert to characters after transliteration in Japanese. I have already done the filter. But then when entering "Joshimaru" it will change to jshmr because when entering jo Andoid will automatically combine the word and convert it into a Japanese character so it will be immediately removed.
Is there any way to solve this problem?
Below is my simple code.
    private boolean isJapaneseCharacter(char c) {
        return Character.UnicodeBlock.of(c) == Character.UnicodeBlock.HIRAGANA ||
                Character.UnicodeBlock.of(c) == Character.UnicodeBlock.KATAKANA ||
                Character.UnicodeBlock.of(c) == Character.UnicodeBlock.CJK_UNIFIED_IDEOGRAPHS ||
                Character.UnicodeBlock.of(c) == Character.UnicodeBlock.HALFWIDTH_AND_FULLWIDTH_FORMS;
    }

    private boolean isAllowedCharacter(char c) {
        if (c <= 255 && (Character.isLetterOrDigit(c))) {
            return true;
        }
        return !isJapaneseCharacter(c)  && !isSpecialCharacter(c);
    }
    private boolean isSpecialCharacter(char c) {
        return !Character.isLetterOrDigit(c);
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        StringBuilder filtered = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            char c = source.charAt(i);
            if (isAllowedCharacter(c)) {
                filtered.append(c);
            }
        }
        return filtered.toString();
    }

Is there any way to solve this problem?
